# To convert activity to handset into a fragment to tablet

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have developed a new feature for my Android aplication that allows you to search various file filtering criteria and press a button to launch a new activity and get a list of the search results. Now I want to modify this functionality in tablet so it can see both activities simultaneously by fragments, ie, on the left side of the screen out the search options and on the right the result list appears when you press the corresponding button.

I tried to adapt my application to use fragments, and for this I changed my class 'ListActivity' (showing results) in a class 'ListFragment', but I'm having several problems with some methods now give me error, such as :

**getIntent ()**

**getSystemService ()**

**findViewById ()**

Toast.**makeText ()**

The error message is as follows:

**"The method getSystemService (String) is undefined for the type MyClass"**

Why I can not use these methods in a 'Fragment' class?

How I can fix it? I need this class as a Fragment, right?

Thank you very much, greetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Fragment, you can use getActivity() to get the activity instance. So for example getActivity().findViewById(R.id.myId)